# Regex search causes VS-Code to crash on macbook

Tags: regex, visual-studio-code

I'm trying to search for a RegEx expression using VS-Code's built-in search option.

Here is the regex: `(?:((\s|\w+|\d+|\]|\))+)(?<!(\bReact\b))(?<dot>\.(?!\.))+)`

As soon as I enter this expression, VS-Code crashes on my macbook.

Is there any way to prevent this?

Comment: Can you add some examples what you tried to match with your regex?

Comment: Your pattern is ECMAScript 2018+ compliant, it is bascially `([\])\s\w]+)(?<!\bReact\b)\.(?!\.)`. If you are using it in the in-document search and replace feature (not the magnifying glass) then it should work.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Other than the named capturing group why wouldn't the regex work in a search across files?

Answer (score -1):

You have `(?<dot>\.(?!\.))+)` a named capturing group in your regex.  I don't believe that is supported in vscode search across files.

In any case, your original regex froze vscode on my Windows machine, but when I removed the named capturing group, the regex worked fine in BOTH the find in a file widget and searching across files.  So this did not freeze vscode for me:

```
(?:((\s|\w+|\d+|\]|\))+)(?<!(\bReact\b))(\.(?!\.))+)
```

I suggest you replace the named capturing group with just a simple capturing group.